# month.abb[] is resulting in incorrect results

Tags: r, string, datetime

I have the following data set. I am trying to split the `date_1` field into month and days. Then converting the month number to a month name.

```
date_1,no_of_births_1
1/1,1482
2/2,1213
3/23,1220
4/4,1319
5/11,1262
6/18,1271
```

I am using `month.abb[]` for converting the month number to name. But instead of providing month name for each value of month number, the result is generating wrong array.
for example: `month.abb[2]` is generating Apr instead of Feb.

```
  date_1 no_of_births_1 V1 V2 month
1    1/1           1482  1  1   Jan
2    2/2           1213  2  2   Apr
3   3/23           1220  3 23   May
4    4/4           1319  4  4   Jun
5   5/11           1262  5 11   Jul
6   6/18           1271  6 18   Aug
```

below is the code i am using,

```
birthday<-read.csv("Birthday_s.csv",header = TRUE)
birthday$date_1<-as.character(birthday$date_1)
#split the data
listx<-sapply(birthday$date_1,function(x) strsplit(x,"/"))
library(base)
#convert to data frame
mat<-as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(listx),ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE))
#combine birthday and mat
birthday2<-cbind(birthday,mat)
#convert month number to month name
birthday2$month<-sapply(birthday2$V1, function(x) month.abb[as.numeric(x)])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run your code, I get the correct months. However, your code is more complicated than necessary. Here are two ways to extract month and day from `date_1`:

First, when you read the data, use `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`, which prevents strings from getting converted to factors.

```
birthday <- read.csv("Birthday_s.csv",header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

**Extract month and days using date functions:**

```
library(lubridate)

birthday$month = month(as.POSIXct(birthday$date_1, format="%m/%d"), abbr=TRUE, label=TRUE)
birthday$day = day(as.POSIXct(birthday$date_1, format="%m/%d"))
```

**Extract month and days using Regular Expressions:**

```
birthday$month = month.abb[as.numeric(gsub("([0-9]{1,2}).*", "\\1", birthday$date_1))]
birthday$day = as.numeric(gsub(".*/([0-9]{1,2}$)", "\\1", birthday$date_1))
```

Comment: I was trying to extract the month names without using date functions. Yes it makes more complicated.